# Style area tag's "title" attribute

Tags: html, css

I created an area on an image and I'm trying to display a description when I hover over it. I couldn't find a better way to do that, so I choose to add the description as the title.

It looks like a plain html tooltip so I'm searching for a way to style it or an alternate way to display a description when hovering. Thank you

Code so far:

```html
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/x11LcrM/team.png" usemap="#image-map" />
    <map name="image-map">
      <div><area
        target="_blank"
        alt="leftGirl"
        title="What is Lorem Ipsum?
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
         Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
         , when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a
          type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the 
          leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was 
          popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem
           Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
           PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. https://www.lipsum.com/"
        href="https://www.webs.com/themes"
        coords="59,669,21,848,75,1151,12,1439,288,1448,568,1446,548,1008,474,691,426,612,400,341,301,281,198,367,161,618"
        shape="poly"
      />
    </map>
```

Comment: Please provide a code of what you have achieved so far.

Comment: How a `title` attribute is displayed is up to the browser. It's one of those bits we have very little control over (like scroll bars or select inputs) However I imagine it might be possible to build your own tooltip instead.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824122/hover-texts-for-separate-positions-on-a-single-photo/72826999#72826999

Comment: @Martin edited the post with the current code

Comment: Your snippet does not work.

Comment: @Martin sorry, a small mistake was there. Check it now

Answer (score 1):

I would say what you're looking for could be, in a bit more modern way, achieved with CSS clip path.

```css
.area{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden
}

.area__element{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.area__element--right{
  clip-path: polygon(30% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 70% 100%)
}

.area__title{
  position: absolute;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #fff;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.area__element:hover .area__title{
  visibility: initial;
}

.area__title--right{
  top: .5em;
  right: .5em;
}

.area__title--left{
  bottom: .5em;
  left: .5em;  
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
  <a href="/a" class="area__element area__element--left">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    <span class="area__title area__title--left">Title one</span>
  </a>
  
  <a href="/b" class="area__element area__element--right">    
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/540/354">
    <span class="area__title area__title--right">Title two</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to do it within a single picture

Comment: @FaideMercer you can very easily modify this, just remove the images from <a> tags and, instead, put one in the `.area` div.